# Qml contents doesn't appear under Windows

Tags: windows, qt, qml

QML contents doesn't appear under Windows for a fresh QML project, that was generated by QtCreator.

Here is what I did :

- I have generated a project using QtCreator => New project... => Application (Qt Quick) => Qt Quick Application - Scroll => using CMake as the build system
- Using QtCreator I have built the app in Release build configuration.
- I have moved the built *.exe to a freshly created, empty folder.
- I called
  C:/Qt/5.12.2/msvc2017_64/bin/windeployqt.exe QtCreatorScrollProject.exe --release --qmldir=c:\Users<myUserName>\Documents\QtCreatorScrollProject
  to deploy the Qt dependencies next to the project.

When I run this build on my development machine, it works fine :
[image]

When I try to run the exact same app on a fresh virtual machine, the window appears, but the QML contents inside of the window are not visible ( == the scrollable list doesn't appear ) :
[image]

I guessed that it is a deployment issue, so I tried to follow this guide : https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows . I followed these steps :
"

Copy the following into C:\Deployment

The release version of MyApp.exe

All the .dll files from C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\bin

All the folders from C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\plugins

(If you used QML) All the folders from C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\qml

"

which I actually had to translate to these steps for myself :
"

Copy the following into C:\Deployment

The release version of QtCreatorScrollProject.exe

All the .dll files from C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017_64\bin

All the folders from C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017_64\plugins

(If you used QML) All the folders from C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017_64\qml
"

But even after having done this, the app doesn't show the QML contents.

So I checked these additional things :
A bit more info :
Here is the output of the app when I run it with `QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1` :

```
> set QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1

> QtCreatorScrollProject.exe
warning: Environment variable QT_LOGGING_TO_CONSOLE is deprecated, use
QT_ASSUME_STDERR_HAS_CONSOLE and/or QT_FORCE_STDERR_LOGGING instead.
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/qml"
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "qrc:/qt-project.org/imports"
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6"
QQmlImports(qrc:/main.qml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick" 2.12 as
""
QQmlImports(qrc:/main.qml)::importExtension: loaded
"C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick.2/qmldir"
QQmlImportDatabase::registerPluginTypes: "QtQuick" from
"C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick.2"
QQmlImports(qrc:/main.qml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick.Controls" 2.5
as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/main.qml)::importExtension: loaded
"C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick/Controls.2/qmldir"
QQmlImportDatabase::registerPluginTypes: "QtQuick.Controls" from
"C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick/Controls.2"
QQmlImports(qrc:/main.qml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick" 2.0 as
"QmlInternals"
QQmlImports(qrc:/main.qml)::importExtension: loaded
"C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick.2/qmldir"
QQmlImports(qrc:/main.qml)::resolveType: "ScrollView" =>
"" QUrl("qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollView.qml") TYPE/URL
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollView.qml)::addLibraryImport:
"QtQuick" 2.12 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollView.qml)::importExtension:
loaded "C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick.2/qmldir"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollView.qml)::addLibraryImport:
"QtQuick.Controls" 2.12 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollView.qml)::importExtension:
loaded "C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick/Controls.2/qmldir"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollView.qml)::addLibraryImport:
"QtQuick.Controls.impl" 2.12 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollView.qml)::addLibraryImport:
"QtQuick.Templates" 2.12 as "T"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollView.qml)::importExtension:
loaded "C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick/Templates.2/qmldir"
QQmlImportDatabase::registerPluginTypes: "QtQuick.Templates" from
"C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick/Templates.2"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollView.qml)::resolveType:
"ScrollBar" => "" QUrl("qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml") TYPE/URL
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::addLibraryImport:
"QtQuick" 2.12 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::importExtension: loaded
"C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick.2/qmldir"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::addLibraryImport:
"QtQuick.Controls" 2.12 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::importExtension: loaded
"C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick/Controls.2/qmldir"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::addLibraryImport:
"QtQuick.Controls.impl" 2.12 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::addLibraryImport:
"QtQuick.Templates" 2.12 as "T"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::importExtension: loaded
"C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick/Templates.2/qmldir"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::resolveType:
"Transition" => "QQuickTransition" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::resolveType:
"Rectangle" => "QQuickRectangle" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::resolveType:
"NumberAnimation" => "QQuickNumberAnimation" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::resolveType:
"T.ScrollBar" => "QQuickScrollBar" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::resolveType:
"SequentialAnimation" => "QQuickSequentialAnimation"
TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::resolveType:
"PauseAnimation" => "QQuickPauseAnimation" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::resolveType:
"State" => "QQuickState" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::resolveType:
"PropertyChanges" => "QQuickPropertyChanges" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml)::addImplicitImport
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollView.qml)::resolveType:
"T.ScrollView" => "QQuickScrollView" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollView.qml)::addImplicitImport
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollView.qml)::resolveType:
"ScrollBar" => "" QUrl("qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml") TYPE/URL
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollView.qml)::resolveType:
"ScrollBar" => "" QUrl("qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ScrollBar.qml") TYPE/URL
QQmlImports(qrc:/main.qml)::resolveType: "ListView" =>
"QQuickListView" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/main.qml)::resolveType: "ApplicationWindow" =>
"" QUrl("qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ApplicationWindow.qml") TYPE/URL
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ApplicationWindow.q
ml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick" 2.12 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ApplicationWindow.q
ml)::importExtension: loaded
"C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick.2/qmldir"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ApplicationWindow.q
ml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick.Window" 2.12 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ApplicationWindow.q
ml)::importExtension: loaded
"C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick/Window.2/qmldir"
QQmlImportDatabase::registerPluginTypes: "QtQuick.Window" from
"C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick/Window.2"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ApplicationWindow.q
ml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick.Controls" 2.12 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ApplicationWindow.q
ml)::importExtension: loaded
"C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick/Controls.2/qmldir"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ApplicationWindow.q
ml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick.Controls.impl" 2.12 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ApplicationWindow.q
ml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick.Templates" 2.12 as "T"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ApplicationWindow.q
ml)::importExtension: loaded
"C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick/Templates.2/qmldir"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ApplicationWindow.qml)::resolveType:
"Rectangle" => "QQuickRectangle" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ApplicationWindow.qml)::resolveType:
"T.ApplicationWindow" => "QQuickApplicationWindow" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ApplicationWindow.q
ml)::addImplicitImport
QQmlImports(qrc:/main.qml)::resolveType: "ItemDelegate" =>
"" QUrl("qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ItemDelegate.qml") TYPE/URL
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ItemDelegate.qml)::addLibraryImport:
"QtQuick" 2.12 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ItemDelegate.qml)::importExtension:
loaded "C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick.2/qmldir"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ItemDelegate.qml)::addLibraryImport:
"QtQuick.Controls" 2.12 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ItemDelegate.qml)::importExtension:
loaded "C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick/Controls.2/qmldir"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ItemDelegate.qml)::addLibraryImport:
"QtQuick.Controls.impl" 2.12 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ItemDelegate.qml)::addLibraryImport:
"QtQuick.Templates" 2.12 as "T"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ItemDelegate.qml)::importExtension:
loaded "C:/Users/User/Downloads/6/6/QtQuick/Templates.2/qmldir"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ItemDelegate.qml)::resolveType:
"IconLabel" => "QQuickIconLabel" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ItemDelegate.qml)::resolveType:
"T.ItemDelegate" => "QQuickItemDelegate" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ItemDelegate.qml)::resolveType:
"Rectangle" => "QQuickRectangle" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qt-
project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/ItemDelegate.qml)::addImplicitImport
QQmlImports(qrc:/main.qml)::resolveType: "QmlInternals.Component"
=> "QQmlComponent" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/main.qml)::addImplicitImport
```

Also : "Accessibility Insights for Windows" app shows that there is
something there, it is just not visible :
[image]

A bit more info :

- the app works well under a Windows7 VM (everything appears, including QML
  contents)
- the app doesn't show the QML contents under Windows8 and Windows10 VMs
  (empty window - QML contents doesn't appear)

Here is the context of the Windows7 VM (as shown by OpenGL Extension Viewer),
where the QML contents does appear :
[image]

Here is the context of the Windows10 VM (as shown by OpenGL Extension Viewer),
where the QML contents doesn't appear :
[image]

I tried a lot of approaches to fix this issue : from updating all the drivers, to trying to force to different renderers. Nothing worked so far.

Comment: You don't show the source code of the app. Are you calling out a specific font that isn't available in Windows 8 and 10?

Comment: As I mentioned it is a freshly created (unmodified) project, generated by Qt Creator so it is easily reproducible by doing the same. Anyways : here is the source : https://github.com/szigetics/QtCreatorScrollProject .

Comment: Have you tried changing the theme in qtquickcontrols2.conf to something other than Default?

Comment: Have you tried using windeployqt.exe instead of gathering dependencies by hand? More info: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool

Comment: @DavidK.Hess : 
"Have you tried changing the theme in qtquickcontrols2.conf to something other than Default?"
Do you think that it could help? I would expect a fresh QtCreator project to just simply work.

"Have you tried using windeployqt.exe instead of gathering dependencies by hand?"
Yes. As I mentioned I did try windeployqt : 
"I called C:/Qt/5.12.2/msvc2017_64/bin/windeployqt.exe QtCreatorScrollProject.exe --release --qmldir=c:\Users<myUserName>\Documents\QtCreatorScrollProject to deploy the Qt dependencies next to the project."

Comment: Re: .conf edit, who knows. At this point turn every knob and see if it has any effect so you have a better clue of where to look. Have you double-checked that the Qt build you are using is built with ANGLE and that the ANGLE libs are being bundled with your app? Try adding an image to your test code to determine if this is just a text rendering issue or if nothing at all displays.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess : 
I am using an official build of Qt. Based on
the Qt documentation it means that it is compiled with `-opengl dynamic`.
Which means that my Qt build should have proper fallback mechanism in place.

Comment: Quoting the Qt documentation from https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-
requirements.html :
"
Dynamically Loading Graphics Drivers
In addition to the build time configuration, Qt supports choosing and loading
the OpenGL implementation at runtime. To use this mode, pass -opengl dynamic
to the configure script.

configure -opengl dynamic
Note: As of Qt 5.5 this is the configuration used by the official, pre-built
binary packages of Qt. It is strongly recommended to use it also in custom
builds, especially for Qt binaries that are deployed alongside applications.
"

Comment: I have set the `QT_OPENGL` environment variable to `angle` and now the QML
contents appear.
Does this mean that Qt's support for choosing and loading the OpenGL
implementation at runtime doesn't properly work all the time?

Comment: In case if I would like to make sure that my app appears on the widest possible set of Windows versions and graphics cards, should I always use 
`QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);`
 
(
which -based on the documentation - forces the app to use ANGLE : 
"Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES
Equivalent to setting QT_OPENGL to angle."
) 
?

Would it be even better to build my own Qt and use `configure ... -angle` to shrink the size of my application (by skipping deploying the OpenGL libraries unnecessarily)?

Comment: @DavidK.Hess : Could you please add the answer to this page so I could approve it as the correct solution? :)

(The answer is that one must set the `QT_OPENGL` env. variable to `angle` . Or : compile Qt with `configure ... -angle` . Or : call `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);` before creating the QApplication object .)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the lack of rendering output, it is likely an issue with OpenGL. Qt 5 is based on OpenGL and Windows (and other platforms) have been supporting it less and less. It requires proper OpenGL drivers with a proper level of OpenGL support to work natively.

That's why Qt optionally uses ANGLE. This is an emulation layer that translates GL calls in Qt to DirectX driver calls - therefore bypassing the issue of missing or insufficient OpenGL drivers.

Forcing the use of ANGLE in your packaged app should fix it if that's the issue.

Comment: Indeed : forcing to use ANGLE fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Qt 6, ANGLE no longer exists. You can force OpenGL in code, at the beginning of main.cpp:

```
#include <QQuickWindow>
...
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)  
    QQuickWindow::setGraphicsApi(QSGRendererInterface::OpenGL);  
#endif
```

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-graphics.html for details.